# Find solution for the following system: $x'=y^3-4x$ , $y'=y^3-y-3x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Find solution for the following system: $x'=y^3-4x$ , $y'=y^3-y-3x$

As I found the three equilibrium points, $(0,0)$ , $(-2,-2)$ , $(2,2)$ .

I am wondering how to find the solution for this one since they are not fully decoupled or partially decoupled?

Thank you

Comment: what do you jean by 'invariant' xy is time invariant so $ \frac{d (xy)}{dt }=0 $

Answer (score 0):

you could try that

$$ x' +4x = y^{3}=y' +y +3x $$ so $ x'-y' = y -x $ then $ y-x =Ae^{-t} $ for a constant A

Comment: you could only find solution for y - x by doing this right? How do you find solution for (x,y)?

Comment: you know  $ y-x=f(t) $ for some function now you should replace this identity inside your equation :D

Comment: Could you show me first several steps of your process?